# In my program, all lines except the first have an apostrophe in front of them, I will link my code below. Any Idea how to get rid of them?

Tags: python, csv

```
rows = ["['1'", "'344'", "'703'", "'727'", "'259'", "'428']\n", "['2'", "'410'", "'446'", "'315'", "'409'", "'263']\n", "['3'", "'800'", "'649'", "'620'", "'538'", "'502']\n", "['4'", "'456'", "'650'", "'618'", "'537'", "'501']\n", "['5'", "'338'", "'756'", "'500'", "'509'", "'659']\n", "['6'", "'755'", "'647'", "'616'", "'534'", "'459']\n", "['7'", "'622'", "'646'", "'614'", "'504'", "'458']\n", "['8'", "'543'", "'645'", "'613'", "'531'", "'556']\n", "['9'", "'700'", "'644'", "'612'", "'530'", "'457']\n", "['10'", "'648'", "'643'", "'610'", "'529'", "'506']\n", "['11'", "'728'", "'642'", "'609'", "'527'", "'455']\n", "['12'", "'655'", "'641'", "'608'", "'526'", "'454']\n", "['13'", "'805'", "'640'", "'606'", "'525'", "'435']\n", "['14'", "'557'", "'639'", "'605'", "'524'", "'453']\n", "['15'", "'535'", "'638'", "'604'", "'522'", "'452']\n", "['16'", "'447'", "'637'", "'602'", "'521'", "'451']\n", "['17'", "'431'", "'636'", "'601'", "'520'", "'450']\n", "['18'", "'503'", "'635'", "'600'", "'519'", "'439']\n", "['19'", "'533'", "'634'", "'558'", "'517'", "'449']\n"]
for row in rows:
  r1 = row.replace('[','')
  r2 = r1.replace('\'','')
  r3 = r2.replace(']','')
  r4 = r3.replace(',','')
  if len(r4) == 1 or len(r4) == 2:
    print(f'{r4}: ',end='')
  elif len(r4) != 1 and len(r4) != 2:
    print(f'{r4},',end='')
```

Also, Here's what it currently outputs:

```
1: 344,703,727,259,428
,2: 410,446,315,409,263
,3: 800,649,620,538,502
,4: 456,650,618,537,501
,5: 338,756,500,509,659
,6: 755,647,616,534,459
,7: 622,646,614,504,458
,8: 543,645,613,531,556
,9: 700,644,612,530,457
,10: 648,643,610,529,506
,11: 728,642,609,527,455
,12: 655,641,608,526,454
,13: 805,640,606,525,435
,14: 557,639,605,524,453
,15: 535,638,604,522,452
,16: 447,637,602,521,451
,17: 431,636,601,520,450
,18: 503,635,600,519,439
,19: 533,634,558,517,449
,
```

I'm mostly wondering how I can either remove the apostrophes or move them to the end of the row above. Any help appreciated.

Comment: is it a one-time process??? If so you may use some inbuilt shortcuts of VS-Code and Sublime Text To get rid of/fix them.

Comment: You need a [mcve] within the question itself. Links die

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last line: print(f'{r4},',end='')

After the {r4} delete the , and u will be fine

Comment: Well, except I would also like to keep the apostrophes from after the :. How do I only get rid of the other ones? @huhu

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

```
for row in rows:
  r1 = row.replace('[','')
  r2 = r1.replace('\'','')
  r3 = r2.replace(']','')
  r4 = r3.replace(',','')
  if len(r4) == 1 or len(r4) == 2:
    if r4 == '1':
      print(f' {r4}',end=': ')
    else:
      print(f'{r4}',end=': ')
  elif len(r4) >= 3:
    print(f'{r4} ',end='')
```

It now prints:

```
 1: 344 703 727 259 428
 2: 410 446 315 409 263
 3: 800 649 620 538 502
 4: 456 650 618 537 501
 5: 338 756 500 509 659
 6: 755 647 616 534 459
 7: 622 646 614 504 458
 8: 543 645 613 531 556
 9: 700 644 612 530 457
 10: 648 643 610 529 506
 11: 728 642 609 527 455
 12: 655 641 608 526 454
 13: 805 640 606 525 435
 14: 557 639 605 524 453
 15: 535 638 604 522 452
 16: 447 637 602 521 451
 17: 431 636 601 520 450
 18: 503 635 600 519 439
 19: 533 634 558 517 449
```